# Echo is off error or Echo is on error coming on runing the batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
set /p str=%1

:MSTART

 set /p ch=%str:~0,1%
 IF '%ch%' == '.' GOTO MEQUAL
 echo %ch%
 goto MEND

 :MEQUAL
call cd..
set /p str=%str:~1%
goto MSTART

:MEND
```

The desired output is if we run the batch file as "mcd ..." it should go back by three directory. 
But it gives Echo is off/ Echo is on Error on running depending on @echo on or @echo off.
How can i fix this issue

This seems to work

```
@echo off
set str=%1

:MSTART

set ch=%str:~0,1%
IF '%ch%' == '.' GOTO MEQUAL
goto MEND

:MEQUAL
call cd..
IF NOT [str] == [] set str=%str:~1%
goto MSTART

:MEND
```

But it gives error '1' was unexpected at this time after complition. I suppose this line is the culprit IF NOT [str] == [] set str=%str:~1% but how to fix this?

Comment: Why is this tagged as a PHP question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is coming  from echo %ch% because %ch% is blank... so you are displaying the ECHO setting.  Try:

```
echo(%ch%
```

or

```
echo.%ch%
```

Edit
Add this to the beginning  of your posted file.

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" goto :MEND
set "str=%~1"
```

Comment: Thanks RGuggisberg, echo.%ch% worked. but why is %ch% blank and not pointing to the first character of str. Name of my batch file is mcd and i am running it as " mcd ... "

Comment: Well, that's a whole 'nother question, totally unrelated to the error is on/off problem you first raised. Now questions aren't that tightly rationed, so you should really raise another for your new problem. The reason for the new problem is that `[str]` is a string, and it can never be equal to `[]`. `[%str%]` might, if `str` is empty, but a better way to check that is `IF DEFINED str`. As it stands, the first character will be repeatedly removed from `str` until it becomes empty, and that will cause the syntax problem with the `set ch...`

Comment: Peter makes a good point.  The question seems to have changed and now we are no longer sure where we are at.  For the original question... you should probably check to make sure %1 is not blank.  See my edited answer.
set str=%~1